# Cannot access a router configuration page

Tags: configuration, router

Trying to configure router Zyxel Keenetic START.
Connected to notebook via Ethernet USB Adapter.
Corresponding Network indicator at the router activ (glowing). 
Internet connected to the notebook port.

**Problem:** trying to access the router configuration page (192.168.1.1) have no results, i.e. no access to the Conf. Page.

Please advise.
S.K.

Comment: Did you check it should be 192.168.1.1? Cuz that should be the only thing   preventing to show you its page.

Comment: The instructions here do mention 192.168.1.1 > http://rudevice.ru/zyxel/zyxel-keenetic-start but it can be other if someone changed it. Open the connection info and confirm the gateway.

Comment: You can always check what the default route is on your system from a terminal by running `netstat -r | awk '/default/ {print $2}'` which should return an IP address where your router might be.

Comment: @Terrance `netstat -r` won't show that address.

Comment: @SergeyKasimov please add extra info to your question, not by editing my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Terrance **Of course I tested it before I commented**. Turns out the reason that it didn't work for me is because I've got my router and its address defined in /etc/hosts, so your command returned "caspurr.local".

Comment: @heynnema That still should work.  Mine returns DD-WRT.local that works fine in a browser.  But that is OK.   I wrote an answer showing both.

Answer (score 4):

Unless the router you are using needs to be fully reset or your system is not running DHCP to receive IP addresses, the following commands could help you in getting to your router.

The `ip` command, or the older command of `netstat` can both show you the route that your network follows.  `ip route` will show the routes for all network as well as `netstat -r`.  I will give examples of both below:

```
:~$ ip route
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.100 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

and

```
:~$ netstat -r
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         DD-WRT.local    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.122.0   *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 virbr0
```

For this command to access your router, we are going to use the `ip` command from a command line in terminal.  The command `xdg-open` can be used to launch the default whatever application we are trying to open from web browsers to text editors, but we are only concerned with web browsers right now.

Using `ip` with `awk` we can grab from the output the address to our default router like so:

```
:~$ ip route | awk '/default/ {print $3}'
10.0.0.1
```

Now, we can take that same command and combine it with `xdg-open` to open our web browser right to the router page:

```
xdg-open http://$(ip route | awk '/default/ {print $3}')
```

which opened my browser right to my router.  I have a WRT router and that is the login page for what I have.

[image]

---

With `netstat -r`:

First, `netstat -r` shows my route as `DD-WRT.local` which is generated from my router itself.  But it is still a route.

Using `ping` to show name to IP resolution:

```
:~$ ping -c 2 $(netstat -r | awk '/default/ {print $2}')
PING DD-WRT.local (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from DD-WRT.local (10.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.780 ms
64 bytes from DD-WRT.local (10.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.19 ms

--- DD-WRT.local ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.780/0.989/1.198/0.209 ms
```

We can see that `DD-WRT.local` resolves to the same IP of `10.0.0.1` so now we can use the `xdg-open` command with it to go directly to my router.

```
xdg-open http://$(netstat -r | awk '/default/ {print $2}')
```

[image]

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: nice answer. doesn't work though - at least, not on this particular router with which I have the same problem, whose config page can be accessed from windows but not from Linux/Ubuntu.

Comment: @markling You might want to try using Chrome with the UA Spoofer plugin installed and maybe fake out the router into thinking you are using a different OS.  I know that some pages they scan for OS type and they don't work like Vudu won't play in Linux because they feel that Linux doesn't support DRM or something like that properly.  Who knows.

Comment: simply using Chrome worked. Now I wonder what tweaks I made to Firefox config.

Comment: NoScript. Turn off NoScript ._.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Ubuntu Unity, just pull down the network icon, and at the bottom of the menu, select `Connection Information`. There you'll see the gateway address... common addresses would be 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1.

Use your web browser to go to that gateway address, and you should be sitting at the router login page.

```
http://192.168.0.1
```